# Correct usage of std::variant_alternative_t

Tags: c++

my aim is to get the name of the type at the current index of std::variant. All i know is the current index of the variable.
I tried different approaches, but to be honest, I cannot understand the documentation (cppreference) anymore in a large extent. All these overloaded templates are way to complicated for my without a piece of working code.

I guess std::variant_alternative_t could be helpful, but the documentation is incomplete (no example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant_alternative).

Lets assume the following example.

```
std::variant<int, float> testVariant{ 12.2f };

std::cout << std::get<1>(testVariant); // Everything is cool
//std::cout << std::get<testVariant.index()>(testVariant) // Unfortunately, incorrect syntax 
//... why ever, i dont see any difference to the line above

//std::variant_alternative_t<???>(???) i dont have any cloud how to use it
```

Comment: You cant use a runtime index though.

Comment: Template arguments must be compile-time constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct usage involves two template arguments: The index and the variant type that you want to index into.

```
using MyIndexedType = std::variant_alternative_t<1, std::variant<int, float>>;
```

or, if you want to neither spell out the full variant nor give it a type alias name (`using MyVariant = std::variant<int, float>`), use `decltype`:

```
using MyIndexedType = std::variant_alternative_t<1, decltype(testVariant)>;
```

Be aware though that the index must be known at compile-time. You can't get around having to know all static types at compile-time.

Comment: Thank you, but i mean i know the index at runtime. Thus, what i want to achieve is not possible without switch case statements ... so its useless to use std:.variant ;( If i would know the index at compile time I could simply write "float", because float is the type at index 1
So ... maintain the code for every new possiblity.

Comment: @StephanH You're supposed to use visitors (which ultimately have a `switch` inside them). Variant is not "useless" if you use it correctly.

Comment: @StephanH Did you look at the other answer?

Comment: @interjay You are right, the other answer seems to be the solution of my problem. However, considering the title of my questions this is the correct answer, too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *visit* the variant, which will generate all of the branching for you:

```
std::visit([&](auto const &value) {
    std::cout << "Index " << testVariant.index() << ", ";
    std::cout << "type " << typeid(decltype(value)).name() << ", ";
    std::cout << "value " << value << '\n';
}, testVariant);
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6IuXUR6TJ7NmLgt6)

Comment: I'll visit you.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Sure, but I hope you like coffee and leeks!

Comment: I guess I'm lucky leeks are my favourite.

Comment: ty, this helps a lot